# Google Play: App's not visible with its name, but with a part of its name?

Tags: android, google-play

My Application is called "Notificator for Steam", when I search for it it gives me the Steam App and a lot of bs, like the App of a soccer team. When I search for just "Notificator", it's on place 20 or so. Any Tips or a reason for this?
de.fosefx.steamnotificator

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its about SEO, not programming.

Comment: What! In some point you have to write the code for SEO to work, and for doing so you have to understand how is that SEO programming works!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about SEO and not programming or coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think google take the words separately so it will take "Notificator","for" and "Steam". It will take the more popular tag so it will be Steam.

Hope it helps.

Comment: do you think they allow the name "SteamNotificator"? I'm asking because they rejected "Steam Notificator"(with space)

Comment: I think you can.